# Unable to access a blob within a container with access type "Blob" from my HDInsight cluster

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to access a blob within a container with access type "Blob" from my HDInsight cluster. But when I do a: -

hadoop fs -text wasb://myconatiner@***.blob.core.windows.net/file.csv

I get the following exception:

> org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container ** in account **.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.

So is this an expected behavior and I cannot access it with with access type "Blob"? But this works if the access type is "Container". Please note my storage account is not linked with the cluster i.e it not configured as a default or additional storage account in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

This is permission issue. You need to add this storage account as additional storage account to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

> So is this an expected behavior and I cannot access it with access type "Blob"?

It is not the expected behavior if just read the data from the blob while  a container with access type "Blob".

It will have read-only permission to the blob in the containers if the container access type **Blob**. We can get more info from the azure [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#using-azure-storage-with-hdinsight-clusters).

> Containers in the storage accounts that are connected to a cluster: Because the account name and key are associated with the cluster during creation, you have full access to the blobs in those containers.
>   Public containers or public blobs in storage accounts that are NOT connected to a cluster: You have read-only permission to the blobs in the containers.
>   Note
>
> **Public containers** (**Container**) allow you to get a list of all blobs that are available in that container and get container metadata.
>
> **Public blobs** (**Blob**) allow you to access the blobs only if you know the exact URL. For more information, see [Restrict access to containers and blobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsazure/dd179354.aspx).

According to the exception that you mentioned, I assume that you may have other operations to do with container such as **list blobs** in the container or **get container metadata** etc. These operations are not allowed with container access type **Blob**, but it is allowed with container type **Container**.

Comment: This is read command for hadoop and if they say that HDInsight would work with access type "Blob" then HDInsight should be able to read it. One thing could be that API's of hadoop HDInsight is trying to get some more info maybe from the container and that's the reason its failing.